# Do I need a protection circuit when using a TP4056 LiPo charging PCB?

Tags: protection, lipo

I'm building a small handheld controller and I am using a small cheap TP4056 PCB for LiPo charging. Do I need to add in a protection circuit that cuts off power from the charger to the rest of the board?

The PCB is all running off of 3.3 V and I am worried if power from the charger and the battery both enter the PCB at the same time it can cause issues.

I could make some kind of circuit that when the charging board is plugged in it cuts off the battery and charger from the rest of the board to protect it.

Am I over-thinking this or is it a good idea?

Comment: The battery can either charge or discharge. So depending on how much current your charger outputs, and how much the device consumes, only the remaining current is going into battery. Or coming out of it. The charger may have problems determining when battery is full.

Comment: I see your point, I think putting a mosfet cutoff would be wise and so it won't have that issue.

Comment: An alternative would be to use a power connector with a pair of contacts that open when a plug is inserted.

Comment: Do you have an example of this?